# TypeOrm many-to-one multiple column join - Referenced column <column name> was not found in entity <entity name>

Tags: node.js, typescript, database, relationship, typeorm

I have a entity A with a composite primary key and a B entity that has foreign keys to both columns. I am trying to create a many-to-one relationship between B (many) and A (one).

When loading the library it throws the following error "Referenced column  was not found in entity "

I'm following the official for [@ManyToOne](https://typeorm.io/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations) and [@JoinColumn](https://typeorm.io/relations#joincolumn-options) decorators as the column names in the database and the entities are not the same.

---

I'm building a database to store scores of a game for a given profile. We have a game profile and store multiple scores in the same game profile.

Simplified version of the code I'm using (unneeded code removed), I'm using TypeScript and it compiles with no errors.

Profile.ts

```
@Entity({ name: "profiles" })
class Profile {
  @PrimaryColumn({ name: "profile_id" })
  profileId!: number;

  @PrimaryColumn()
  role!: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Score, (score) => score.profile)
  scores!: Array<Score>;
}
```

Score.ts

```
@Entity({ name: "scores" })
class Score {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  @ManyToOne(
    () => Profile,
    (profile) => profile.scores
  )
  @JoinColumn([
    {
      name: "profile_profile_id",
      referencedColumnName: "profile_id",
    },
    {
      name: "profile_role",
      referencedColumnName: "role",
    },
  ])
  profile!: Profile;
}
```

Error that the code throws: "Referenced column profile_id was not found in entity Profile".

I have already checked that the names on the entities and columns match with the database and the primary key of the "profiles" table is a single index composed of both the "profile_id" and "role" columns.

I think I'm not missing anything.

Thanks for reading and the patience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have given up and ended up adding a extra numeric, auto-incremental column to use as the id (classical "id" column).

I need to keep the "profileId" and "role" columns unique, so I added a unique-index composed of both columns.

This is the code I have ended up using (removing the unneeded code)

Profile.ts

```
@Entity({ name: "profiles" })
class Profile {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  @Column({ name: "profile_id" })
  profileId!: number;

  @Column()
  role!: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Score, (score) => score.profile)
  scores!: Array<Score>;
}
```

Score.ts

```
@Entity({ name: "scores" })
class Score {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  @ManyToOne(
    () => Profile,
    (profile) => profile.scores
  )
  @JoinColumn([
    {
      name: "profile_profile_id",
      referencedColumnName: "id",
    },
  ])
  profile!: Profile;
}
```